How to correctly use a pyqt5 QTimer and QThreadPool together in QApplication
I am currently trying to use a QTimer object in order to poll an api for differences to the current application but it is never running. I don't know if it is because it's being skipped in my init function with the thread above it or if it is another problem.
Here is what I have so far. The init_thread handles setting up the current state from the api and then I need the QTimer to continue to poll for any changes after this.
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = None
        self.initUI()
        self.initBoard()
        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

       

        init_thread = APIWorker(self.connect_correspondence)
        init_thread.signals.resultSig.connect(self.start_game)
        init_thread.signals.finishedSig.connect(self.handle_api_done)
        init_thread.signals.errorSig.connect(self.handle_api_error)
        self.threadpool.start(init_thread)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        connected = self.timer.timeout.connect(self.check_API_moves)

        if not connected:
            print("Error connecting to QTimer")
        if connected:
            print("Connected")

        
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.start()


        print(f"Timer is running? {self.timer.isActive()}\n")
        time.sleep(.5)
        print(f"Timer remaining time {self.timer.remainingTime()}")


How do you tell that the timer is "never running"? What does check_API_moves do? Do the print() above show proper results? Also, why are you using time.sleep(), which, by the way, is blocking and should never be used in the main thread of a UI toolkit? Please provide a proper [mre].
